# Redirect audio output from a streaming app to a DJ app

Tags: audio, mac

Is it possible? I want to play with the output of streaming radios.

Specifically I'm talking about something like Spin (a streaming app) and Traktor or djay (a DJ app).

I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a free app from Cycling74 called [SoundFlower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) you can use for this. It presents itself as an audio interface but is completely virtual. You use it as the output device in one app and the input device in the other app and you're all set. Audio now passed directly from one app in to the other.

Not sure how well it works with 10.6. But it worked great in 10.5.

Comment: It works great in 10.6.